# Keybaord don't dismiss when done is pressed

Tags: ios, keyboard

I have the following code and my keyboard is not dismissing when the Done button is pressed on the iPad.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if (textField.tag == 13) //Username Field
    {
        UITableViewCell *cCredentials = [self.tvList cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:CredentialsSection]];
        [((UITextField*)[cCredentials viewWithTag:14]) becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField.tag == 14) //Password Field
    {
        if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"NTAuthentication"] isEqualToString: @"N"])
        {
            //Domain Field
            UITableViewCell *cCredentials = [self.tvList cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:CredentialsSection]];
            [((UITextField*)[cCredentials viewWithTag:15]) becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        else
        {
            [textField resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The header file delegates:

```
@interface vcSignature_iPad : UIViewController <DropdownDelegate,
                                                UITextFieldDelegate,
                                                UITextViewDelegate,
                                                UITableViewDataSource,
                                                UITableViewDelegate>
```

This is where I create the fields in the table for the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
UITableViewCell *cellCredentials = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellCredentials"];

    if (cellCredentials == nil)
    {
        cellCredentials = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cellCredentials"];
        cellCredentials.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cellCredentials.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]init];
        txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        txt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        txt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        txt.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        txt.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        txt.delegate = self;
        txt.text = nil;

        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            txt.placeholder = @"User Id";
            txt.tag = 13;
            txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            txt.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, 240.0, 31.0);
            txt.text = stored.User;
            [cellCredentials.contentView addSubview:txt];


            txt = [[UITextField alloc]init];
            txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            txt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
            txt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
            txt.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
            txt.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
            txt.delegate = self;
            txt.text = stored.Password;

            txt.placeholder = @"Password";
            txt.secureTextEntry = YES;
            txt.tag = 14;
            txt.frame = CGRectMake(279.0, 10.0, 240.0, 31.0);
            if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"NTAuthentication"] isEqualToString: @"N"])
            {
                txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            }
            else
            {
                txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
            }
            [cellCredentials.contentView addSubview:txt];
        }
        else
        {
            txt.placeholder = @"Domain";
            txt.tag = 15;
            txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            txt.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, 240.0, 31.0);
            txt.text = stored.Domain;
            [cellCredentials.contentView addSubview:txt];
        }
```

Comment: Have you set up your delegates for the textfields?

Comment: The code snippet that you have posted isn't really detailed enough.. What is the tag of the keyboard that you are trying to dismiss? Like @Flexicoder said, have you set the delegate on that textField correctly? if the text field's tag is 14, is the value of `NTAuthentication` in your user defaults equal to `N`? It might be a good idea to use breakpoints on this method to step through your code to try and isolate your issue.

Comment: @Flexicoder yes I have, the above code has been updated.

Comment: @liamnichols Yes I have added the delegate UITextFieldDelegate. The value for NTAuthentication in this case is "N", when I used the breakpoints if goes to the else part [textfield resignFirstresponder] and then to the return YES. The keyboard is still there it won't go away. The user is only entering the username and password in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are in a UIModalPresentationFormSheet modal view controller's view. By default, the keyboard does *not* disappear when a text field on this kind of modal view resigns first responder. The keyboard vanishes only when the modal view itself is dismissed (or you can change the behavior, by overriding `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` to return NO).

Comment: Thanxs for clarifying this did not know this for the ModalPresentationForm

Comment: You may ask: why am I guessing that you're using UIModalPresentationFormSheet? It's because you already indicated in your comments that breakpointing shows that `[textField resignFirstResponder]` is being called. Now, we know that `textField` is not nil, because it is correctly supplied as part of the delegate method call; otherwise, we wouldn't be here in the first place. Therefore we have to ask ourselves: under what circumstances does `resignFirstResponder` _not_ cause keyboard dismissal? And this is the main one.